# Warn level not show log4net

Tags: c#, xml, log4net

i have the folloging XML to log4net

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppenderXml" />
    </root>
    <appender name="FileAppenderXml" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs\%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\%date{yyyyMMdd}.xml"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
        <locationInfo value="true"/>
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <param name="Encoding" value="utf-8" />
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Using Yalv I started to detect that Warning (WARN) events are not generated by the application. I am using 4 levels (INFO, WARN, DEBUG, ERROR) and only the WARN type is the one not shown.

Here an extract:

```
        switch (typeLog)
        {
            case elogType.infoType:
                log.Info(currentMessage);
                break;

            case elogType.errorType:
                log.Error(currentMessage);
                break;

            case elogType.debugType:
                log.Debug(currentMessage);
                break;

            case elogType.warningType :
                log.Warn(currentMessage);
                break;
        }
```

Could it be some XML configuration or maybe the code?

Comment: Seems odd. Have you looked the actual XML file to see if the `WARN` logs are there?

Comment: Yes, and all event types (levels) except Warm appear. Seems odd to me too.

Comment: Do you have a `LevelRangeFilter` somewhere? I'm not familiar with Yalv so I'm not sure how you can know that only WARN is not generated.

Comment: No, I do not have that statement anywhere in XML.
Yalv is simply a viewer to be able to manage in a more pleasant and comfortable the information coming from log4net when the format is XML. You can find it at https://yalv.codeplex.com/

Comment: I know the WARN is not being generated because I'm triggering events that trigger each of the log4net levels and expressly that event is generated but with the INFO tag and not WARM.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue appear to be that when the WARN event fires but it appears as "INFO."

According to the [documentation:](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Core.Level.html)

> When logging at level INFO the actual level used is not Info but the value of `LoggerRepository.LevelMap["INFO"]`. The default value for this is Info, but this can be changed by reconfiguring the level map.